# Generate and upload reports on the result of a get request in CSV, Excel, PDF to apex oracle

Tags: oracle, rest, api, get, oracle-apex

i got this request, in apex oracle. I upload data there. Is it possible to upload this data in "CSV" format, provided if as_file is "true" ??.that is, I want to write as_file = true when I make this request and upload it to a file !. Thank you for your help)

My GET

```html
declare

  v_count number;

begin

  select count(*)
  into v_count
  from users_c;

  if v_count = 0 then
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('success', false);
    apex_json.write('message', 'No data found');
    apex_json.write('count', 0);
    apex_json.close_object;

    return;
  end if;

  apex_json.open_object;
  apex_json.write('count', v_count);
  apex_json.open_array('items');

  for user_rec in (
    select id,
      login
    from users_c
  )
  loop
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('id', user_rec.id);
    apex_json.write('user', user_rec.login);
    apex_json.open_array('datasectors');

    for org_rec in (
      select id,
        name
      from organizations o
      where id in (
        select organization_id
        from organization_users
        where user_id = user_rec.id
      )
    )
    loop
      apex_json.open_object;
      apex_json.write('id', org_rec.id);
      apex_json.write('name', org_rec.name);
      apex_json.close_object;
    end loop;

    apex_json.close_array; -- datasectors
    apex_json.close_object;
  end loop;

  apex_json.close_array; -- items
  apex_json.close_object;

end;
```

Here is my answer, I want to save it as a file myself

```html
   "items": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "user": "andrii",
          "datasectors": [{
            "id": "21",
              "name": "TOW3"
            }
          ],
          "roles": {
          "role": "Admin"
          }
        }
```

I expect a response

```html
 "id", "user",   "datasectors", "roles"
 "2" , "andrii", "TOW3"       , "Admin"
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do? What do you mean by `as_file = "true"`?

Comment: @DanMcGhan I want to pass in a het, in queer variable as_file , and if it will be = true, then the upload to the csv file happens

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand what you want to do. You said you have a get request? Does that mean you created a REST endpoint with a GET handler? You said you want CSV, Excel, and PDF, but your GET handler is sending JSON. How do you expect to get these file types? You said you want to save it as a file. Do you mean download or do you mean save in the database? Please explain everything in more detail.

Comment: @DanMcGhan yes, you got it right))) I created a REST endpoint using a GET handler. I though CSV, Excel and PDF, but my GET handler sends JSON. From my example answer, I expect the following answer. I completed my question with a reply

Comment: CSV and JSON are easy. But Excel and PDF are not. Those require you to either a) use built-in features that provide those formats or b) build those formats yourself. Doing it yourself is not going to be easy. Have you looked into APEX Office Print (AOP)? https://www.apexofficeprint.com/index.html That may be your best bet.